# Location missing value imputation in R

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R to impute missing values. I have an initial dataframe(`df`) with timeseries loaction (x and y) observations - timestamps are available for the missing observations as well.

I created another dataframe with the start and end timestamps of the periods with missing observations.(`missings`)

Now I want to impute the missing x and y coordinates as equidistant points on a straight line - which I wrote the function `func` for:

```
func <- function(df, missings){  
  for (i in 1:nrow(missings)) {
    Xstart <- df %>%
      filter(TimeStamp == missings[[i,"StartMissing"]]) %>%
      pull(X)
    Xend <- df %>%
      filter(TimeStamp == missings[[i,"EndMissing"]]) %>%
      pull(X)
    n <- df %>%
      filter(TimeStamp > missings[[i,"StartMissing"]] &
             TimeStamp < missings[[i,"EndMissing"]] ) %>%
      nrow()
    
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(X = case_when(
        TimeStamp >  missings[[i,"StartMissing"]] &
        # I think the problem is with the lag() here
        TimeStamp <  missings[[i,"EndMissing"]] ~ lag(X,1) + ((Xend - Xstart) / (n + 1)),
        TRUE ~ X))
  }
  return(df)
}
```

It all works fine except for the missing value imputation. It does not use the lagged values of imputed missing values on accumulating on to the next observations. Is there any other function that can be used (instead of the lag function) or any better approach to handle this?

Data :

```
missings <- data.frame(
  StartMissing = c(1130.132,1206.398,1217.598,1771.732,1784.531),
  EndMissing = c(1205.865,1207.999,1218.665,1784.531,1785.598)
)

dput(df)
structure(list(TimeStamp = c(1130.665, 1131.199, 1131.732, 1132.265, 
1132.799, 1133.332, 1133.865, 1134.399, 1134.932, 1135.465, 1135.999, 
1136.532, 1137.065, 1137.599, 1138.132, 1138.665, 1139.199, 1139.732, 
1140.265, 1140.799, 1141.332, 1141.865, 1142.399, 1142.932, 1143.465, 
1143.999, 1144.532, 1145.065, 1145.599, 1146.132, 1146.665, 1147.199, 
1147.732, 1148.265, 1148.799, 1149.332, 1149.865, 1150.399, 1150.932, 
1151.465, 1151.999, 1152.532, 1153.065, 1153.599, 1154.132, 1154.665, 
1155.199, 1155.732, 1156.265, 1156.799, 1157.332, 1157.865, 1158.399, 
1158.932, 1159.465, 1159.999, 1160.532, 1161.065, 1161.599, 1162.132, 
1162.665, 1163.199, 1163.732, 1164.265, 1164.799, 1165.332, 1165.865, 
1166.399, 1166.932, 1167.465, 1167.999, 1168.532, 1169.065, 1169.599, 
1170.132, 1170.665, 1171.199, 1171.732, 1172.265, 1172.799, 1173.332, 
1173.865, 1174.399, 1174.932, 1175.465, 1175.999, 1176.532, 1177.065, 
1177.599, 1178.132, 1178.665, 1179.199, 1179.732, 1180.265, 1180.799, 
1181.332, 1181.865, 1182.399, 1182.932, 1183.465, 1183.999, 1184.532, 
1185.065, 1185.599, 1186.132, 1186.665, 1187.199, 1187.732, 1188.265, 
1188.799, 1189.332, 1189.865, 1190.399, 1190.932, 1191.465, 1191.999, 
1192.532, 1193.065, 1193.599, 1194.132, 1194.665, 1195.199, 1195.732, 
1196.265, 1196.799, 1197.332, 1197.865, 1198.399, 1198.932, 1199.465, 
1199.999, 1200.532, 1201.065, 1201.599, 1202.132, 1202.665, 1203.199, 
1203.732, 1204.265, 1204.799, 1205.332, 1205.865, 1206.399, 1206.932, 
1207.465, 1207.999, 1208.532, 1209.065, 1209.599, 1210.132, 1210.665, 
1211.199, 1211.732, 1212.265, 1212.799, 1213.332, 1213.865, 1214.399, 
1214.932, 1215.465, 1215.999, 1216.532, 1217.065, 1217.599, 1218.132
), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
517.249, 517.185, NA, NA, 519.711, 516.299, 519.852, 516.178, 
515.869, 518.132, 515.684, 515.559, 515.629, 515.223, 516.892, 
516.89, 517.375, 517.518, 517.909, 516.641, 517.523, 517.887, 
517.636, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -165L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: you could use `df %>% mutate(X = zoo::na.approx(X, na.rm = FALSE))` but the problem of interpolating leading and trailing NAs remains (there is no start or end value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define new `+` and made additional columns.

```
`%+%` <- function(x, y)  mapply(sum, x, y, MoreArgs = list(na.rm = TRUE))

    func <- function(df, missings){  
  for (i in 1:nrow(missings)) {
    Xstart <- df %>%
      filter(TimeStamp == missings[[i,"StartMissing"]]) %>%
      pull(X)
    Xend <- df %>%
      filter(TimeStamp == missings[[i,"EndMissing"]]) %>%
      pull(X)
    n <- df %>%
      filter(TimeStamp > missings[[i,"StartMissing"]] &
               TimeStamp < missings[[i,"EndMissing"]] ) %>%
      nrow()
    diff_X <- (Xend - Xstart) / (n + 1)
    if (is_empty(diff_X) | n == 0) {
    } else {
      nvec <- seq(diff_X, n*diff_X, by = diff_X)
      
      df <- df %>%
        mutate(Y = case_when(
          TimeStamp >  missings[[i,"StartMissing"]] &
            TimeStamp <  missings[[i,"EndMissing"]] ~ diff_X,
          TRUE ~ X))
      df <- df %>%
        mutate(X = case_when(
          TimeStamp >  missings[[i,"StartMissing"]] &
            TimeStamp <  missings[[i,"EndMissing"]] ~ lag(X,1) %+% cumsum(Y),
          TRUE ~ X)) %>% select(-Y)
        }

  }
  return(df)
}
```

If `Xstart` and `Xend` does not exists, It will fill nothing but if they exists, it will work